# Convert an HTML expandable list into tabular or csv format

Tags: html, bash, parsing, csv

I know this topic has been covered a few times but i could not find a case that would apply to mine. I am not an experienced computer user please keep that in mind, although i can play with bash, R and possibly run a perl script too. FYI - I run Ubuntu on my machine.

What i would like to do is to convert the expandable list of the following web page http://www.genome.jp/kegg-bin/get_htext?br08902.keg (please expand completely using the "one-click mode") into a tabular or csv format, where each level of indentation goes to a separate column.

It wouldn't be so bad as well to have the parent categories to be repeated for all the elements grouped below that. Something like the tab below that i made manually for the first few lines of the page.

```
Pathways and Ontologies Pathways    br08901  KEGG pathway maps
Pathways and Ontologies Functional hierarchies  br08902  BRITE functional hierarchies
Genes and Proteins  Orthologs and modules   ko00001  KEGG Orthology (KO)
Genes and Proteins  Orthologs and modules   ko00002  KEGG pathway modules
Genes and Proteins  Orthologs and modules   ko00003  KEGG modules and reaction modules
Genes and Proteins  Protein families: metabolism    ko01000  Enzymes
Genes and Proteins  Protein families: metabolism    ko01001  Protein kinases
Genes and Proteins  Protein families: metabolism    ko01009  Protein phosphatases and associated proteins
Genes and Proteins  Protein families: metabolism    ko01002  Peptidases
Genes and Proteins  Protein families: metabolism    ko01003  Glycosyltransferases
Genes and Proteins  Protein families: metabolism    ko01005  Lipopolysaccharide biosynthesis proteins
Genes and Proteins  Protein families: metabolism    ko01004  Lipid biosynthesis proteins
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: ...and so far what did you try to parse it? Where it doesn't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This task need some well separated steps. Breakdown:

Getting the content of the page. You can use the for example the `curl` or `wget` or `fetch` or similar programs. E.g.

```
curl http://...
```

will download the page content.

In the your page, exist a link "download htext". When you check, where it points, you will discover than you need download from the link

```
http://www.kegg.jp/kegg-bin/download_htext?htext=br08902.keg&format=htext&filedir=
                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^ name of your needed keg
```

so after the

```
curl "http://www.kegg.jp/kegg-bin/download_htext?htext=br08902.keg&format=htext&filedir=" > mykeg.txt
```

will get a file what looks the next: (shortened)

```
+C      Br number
#<h2><a href="/kegg/kegg2.html"><img src="/Fig/bget/kegg3.gif" align="middle" border=0></a>&nbsp; BRITE Functional Hierarchies</h2>
#<!---
#ENTRY       br08902
#NAME        Brite
#DEFINITION  BRITE functional hierarchies
#--->
!
A<b>Pathways and Ontologies</b>
B  Pathways
C    br08901  KEGG pathway maps
B  Functional hierarchies
C    br08902  BRITE functional hierarchies
#
A<b>Genes and Proteins</b>
B  Orthologs and modules
C    ko00001  KEGG Orthology (KO)
C    ko00002  KEGG pathway modules
```

It is a nice text file, mostly without HTML markup. Easily parseable with common bash tools.

First some cleaning up:

removing all unwanted lines with the `sed` command

```
sed '/^[#!+]/d'
```

remove unwanted html markup (generally impossible with regexes, but in this case possible)

```
sed 's/<[^>]*>//g'
```

add delimiter to the leading character

```
sed 's/^./& /'
```

after the above, you get a text like the next

```
A Pathways and Ontologies
B   Pathways
C     br08901  KEGG pathway maps
B   Functional hierarchies
C     br08902  BRITE functional hierarchies
A Genes and Proteins
B   Orthologs and modules
C     ko00001  KEGG Orthology (KO)
C     ko00002  KEGG pathway modules
C     ko00003  KEGG modules and reaction modules
```

what is have a nice, parseable structure with bash

```
while read -r prefix content
do
     echo "do something with a line >>$content<< with a prefix >>$prefix<<"
done
```

you can test the `prefix` for example with the `case` command, like:

```
case "$prefix" in
    A) a="$content" ;;
    B) b="$content" ;;
    C) c="$content" ;;
esac
```

exists an nicer alternative using `associative arrays`, but the above is simple and working...

You now have all informations what you need to make an working solution (in 8 lines).

The next is up to you... ;)

#### Edit

Usually im not doing the whole work, because the stackoverflow is not a free-programming service, but ok - here is the script:

```
kegfile="KEG"
while read -r prefix content
do
    case "$prefix" in
        A) col1="$content" ;;
        B) col2="$content" ;;
        C) echo -e "$col1\t$col2\t$content";;
    esac
done < <(sed '/^[#!+]/d;s/<[^>]*>//g;s/^./& /' < "$kegfile")
```

Comment: @ jm666 - thanks for your very detailed reply. I am trying to follow your indications however when i try to download using curl it creates an empty .txt file. I have run the following `curl "http://www.kegg.jp/kegg-bin/download_htext?htext=q00001.keg&format=htext&filedir=" > KEGG.txt`. I have also tried with wget and it's the same. Any idea what could that be? The main page containing my results is the following http://www.genome.jp/kegg-bin/get_htext?q00001.keg+-p+/tools/kaas/files/log/result/1395737602 in case you want to try yourself, perhaps there is something wrong with the actual page??

Comment: When in the browser you clicks the "download htext", happens nothing (nothing is downloaded nor in the browser). So, probably it is a problem at the actual page.

Comment: Indeed, i noticed that the other link i sent you the htext actually downloads a file when you click on it. I will try to figure this problem first, but i am sure your solution will work! Thanks again.

Comment: I didn't get any file, maybe the server has some timeouts or limits or like. On the worst case, you can download the "htext" with a browser and use the script only for processing...

Comment: @ jm666 - I made it work. I have a couple of questions though. When i clean up using sed shall input just the filename e.g. `sed '/[^#!+]/d' mykeg.txt` or shall i send this into a `> newfile.txt`? The second option does not seem to produce anything significant, while the first seems to operate in bash but i am not sure if it also modified the main file (seems the same to me). Sorry but i have never used this function before and cant get around it from the help. 
I am also not sure about the second part for parsing, shall i input that as is or modify it to my needs? I am not quite sure. :)

Comment: @ jm666 - I totally understand your point and i appreciate the fact that you did it anyway! For people like me, biologists that try to use informatic tools for their work, the help from people like you is invaluable. It can save me two days for a simple task (for you). Really, thanks!!!

Comment: enjoy the script - will ask you when I will need some biologics info.. ;)

Comment: FYI - worked beautifully and i was even able to add a D) on my own. :-)
By all means, if i can ever help i would love to do so!

Comment: Tried to edit it, but no enough characters, the sed '/[^#!+]/d' mykeg.txt should be sed '/^[#!+]/d' mykeg.txt.

Comment: @gyger missed the point, the script contains your regex, e.g. `done < <(sed '/^[#!+]/d;s/<[^>]*>//g;s/^./& /' < "$kegfile")` so, exactly the `'/^[#!+]/d;` is here...

Comment: Sorry, to unspecific in the script it is, but in the intial explanation, were you explain it step by step it is wrong.